# How to detect the small amount change in a big file(TB)

Tags: algorithm, bigdata

I just found an interesting blog talking about some interview questions. One of the question is:

> Given a very large file (multiple TB), detect what 4MB ranges has changed in the file between consecutive runs of your program.

I don't have any clues on this. Can anyone give some ideas on this?

Comment: Assuming the old file still exists, read a 4MB block from both files, compare, then read the next block, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have any control on the creation of the data you can use **[Merkle trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree)**

Split the data into small fragments (let's say 10MB each, but it's not the issue), and for each fragment create a `h=hash(fragment)`.

Now, all these hashes will be the leaves of the tree. Now, create a full binary tree from the leaves up: `h(father) = hash(father.left XOR father.right)`.

Now, you've got yourself a tree - and if you compare two trees, h(root1) = h(root2) if and only if tree1=tree2 - with high probability (if you use a 128 bits hash, the probability to mistake is 1/2^128, which is really negligible).

The same claim is correct for any subtrees of course, and this allows you to quickly find the leaf which is different, and this leaf represents the fragment that got changed.

This idea is used by [Amazon's Dynamo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_DynamoDB) to compare if two data bases got changed, and quickly finding the change.

Comment: "Merkle", not "Markele".^_^

Answer (score 0):

you can compare it byte by byte and find the difference. it would take a long time but is worth a try.

another solution right out of my mind is split the file into 500 GB and calculate the md5 value and compare it with the original md5 value of the split. one would be different from the original and you can split that into 250 gb and again compare the the md5 value of the original. and you do it further and further untill you get the 4 mb.

It is similar to the coin problem with a weighing machine with limited number of turns.

Comment: this is inefficient in both time and memory since you need to keep calculating the md5 of big file. Divide and Conquer introduces more overhead than time/ memory saving.